# Spring JmsTemplate single instance for different QoS

Tags: java, spring, jmstemplate

I know that `JmsTemplate` may be shared between multiple threads and used concurrently for sending messages.

But what if I want to share one instance, but send messages with different QoS params - say different priority.

As far as I can see in the source code, if QoS is enabled, `JmsTemplate` uses the overloaded version of the `Producer.send()` with QoS and there is no other way to pass these parameters from outside (apart from setting them directly into a `JmsTemplate` instance)

Setting QoS into a single shared `JmsTemplate` instance right before sending a message is not an option for known reasons.

So the questions are:

- is there a good solution to keep one `JmsTemplate` instance and send messages with beforehand-unknown QoS (e.g. passed from outside)?
- If there is not, how "dirty" is it to create a new instance on each send call then?